# Can we use '?' operator instead of nested-if condition?

Tags: java, if-statement, nested-if

A nested-if condition to be written using the ? : syntax. Is it not an allowed scenario?

Below is the code

```
        int i=(10>5)?(2<5)?230:456;
        System.out.println("i="+i);
```

Which I thought would be equal to

```
if(10>5){
   if(2<5){
        i=230;
   }
   else{
       i=456;
   }
}
```

My idea was that first 10>5 would be evaluated, and as it is true, it would then verify if 2<5 or not. Now since that is also true, "i" should be assigned to 230. 
The error message was

```
ControlFlow.java:10: error: : expected
        int i=(10>5)?(2<5)?230:456;

ControlFlow.java:10: error: ';' expected
        int i=(10>5)?(2<5)?230:456;
                                   ^
ControlFlow.java:11: error: illegal start of expression
        System.out.println("i="+i);
              ^
ControlFlow.java:11: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println("i="+i);
```

Comment: You have two ternaries `?` with only one choice separator `:`. You need as many `?` as `:`. `(10>5) ? (2<5) ? 230 : 456 : 9999` is a valid, if incredibly hard to read, expression.

Comment: both are separated things.. its up to your requirement .!

Comment: IMHO, readability is preferred over the number of code lines. Moreover, why is Javascript tagged in this question??

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt, I tagged javascript because we have ternary operator use in js as well. I was about to edit my code.

Comment: I removed the JavaScript tag, please focus on one language only when asking questions.

Comment: @Aishwarya, yeah we do have but the question posted doesn't

Comment: I would solve this with simply `if ... else if ... else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add a part of the expression. Try it as follows:

```
int i = (10>5) ? ( (2<5) ? 230:456 ) : 0;
```

Replace the above 0 to be the desired number you want your variable to be when your first condition `(10>5)` is false.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator has the syntax

```
aBoolean ? value : value
```

and it will return a value itself, so you can nest them as

```
aBoolean ? (aBoolean ? value : value) : value
```

Your code `(10>5)?(2<5)?230:456;` however is equivalent to

```
aBoolean ? (aBoolean ? value : value)
```

so it is missing the second value for your first ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it may be easier to understand if you rearrange the conditions.

Instead of

`int v = (a > b) ? (c > d) ? 100 : 200 : 300;`

You can do

`int v = (a <= b) ? 300 : (c > d) ? 100 : 200;`

The only difference is in the latter case, the initial condition returns a value immediately when true and requires requires further evaluation when false.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for below solutions. But this is not recommended today as Cognitive complexity of a source code is a considerable matter in industry today. According to the logic which you have shared the same can be implmented in both ways as below.

```
 int i=(10>5) && (2<5)?230:456;
    System.out.println("i="+i);


 int i = (10>5)?(2<5)?230:456:0;
    System.out.println("i="+i);
```

Comment: `(10>5) && (2<5) ? 230 : 456` is completely different condition

Comment: According to the logic , there is no else portion to 10>5 condition. Once its has successfull , it travers to the next condition which is 2<5 . Only this condition expects to have a else portion. Therefor it seems that such logic can be re-written in two conditions combined by AND logic which provides the same answer. It would be great if you can you explain the reason for your comment with an explanation@AndrewTobilko

Comment: But the if combination of 10>5 and 2<5 both fails we can go for returning 456 as per the derived logic from original which provides same answer. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can nest the ternary operator as deep as you can next the if conditions however,  ternary operators being the condensed version of IF conditions, they can make ur code not readable if you condense them deeper.

Just remember to bracket the conditions just to make it readable but it's not a requirement  (0<1) ?